# Why does everyone say that it is better to launch a satellite into polar orbit from the pole than from the equator?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, polar-orbit

If the Earth were spherical, I would agree with this. But the Earth is not spherical. And at the equator, the radius of the Earth is 21 km greater than at the poles. By convention, the altitude of the spacecraft is equal to the distance to the center of the Earth minus approximately 6378.137 kilometers. If the altitude of your target orbit is 200 km, then from the pole you need to rise to 221 km (+21 km relative to the equator).

Even taking into account the fact that you have to counteract the velocity of earth’s spin if you launch from the equator, I think that due to the differences in heights, launching from the equator will still be more effective.
Сorrect me if I am wrong!

Comment: compare the energy difference in height against the energy difference in velocity for your example orbits

Comment: @ErinAnne specific energy $g\times h$ versus $v^2/2$ is higher for the pole example. wouldn't that strengthen OP's argument?

Comment: The whole argument is nonsense; it's _always_ better to launch a satellite from wherever your established launch site facility is located, regardless of trajectory.

Comment: @RussellBorogove - for example SpaceX does not launch from the near the equator (other than Falcon 1 at 9° latitude) even though it would be "better" for many types of launches. However it seems that the intent of the question is about energy advantages, not overall operational logistics. A better wording would be something like, "is there an advantage to launching a satellite into polar orbit from the pole than from the equator? I think the OP could make this type of edit without affecting the existing answer.

Comment: Can you give any example of anyone suggesting launching from the poles? I've never heard of such a thing. So I can assure you "everyone" doesn't say that.

Comment: @RussellBorogove And that's why no space agency ever established a second launch site?

Comment: @Organic Marble Sorry if my question is incorrect. I meant that I read many places that when launching from the equator into a polar orbit, you need to cancel the entire speed of the Earth's rotation, but in fact this value is about 14 m/s, which is confirmed by the results of mathematical modeling.

Comment: @Steve Pemberton yes, you are right. meant specifically about energy advantages, other things being equal

Comment: @JasonPatterson - although it gets into sort of a nuance, generally it's not the trajectory itself per se that is an issue, but what is located underneath the trajectory. At many locations the orbital dynamics would be okay for a particular launch, but geopolitical and/or safety considerations can force trajectories that are not ideal, or not even possible for a particular rocket/payload/orbit combination. In sort of a reverse situation, for political reasons Russia has been moving launches from Baikonur to Plesetsk and Vostochny even though those high latitude locations are not always ideal.

Comment: the earth is not spherical because it deforms until the entire surface is equipotential when considering the sum of gravitational potential energy and rotational kinetic energy.  The energy cost to go from polar ground height to equatorial ground height is equal to the energy cost to remove equatorial rotation speed in the absence of air resistance, mountains, etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When looking only at the required $\Delta v$, and modeling Earth as a
uniform oblate spheroid, launching into a 90 degree polar orbit from the
equator is indeed more expensive than doing so from one of the poles,
despite the altitude advantage, but only marginally.

First, let's look at the cost of canceling the Earth rotation velocity
when launching from the equator.  At the equator, Earth's surface is
moving 465 m/s to the east relative to its center.  Meanwhile, for a
target orbit altitude of 200 km, the required orbital velocity is about
7800 m/s, and we want to be going north or south to hit the 90 degree
orbit inclination.  To cancel the eastward motion, basic trigonometry
shows we need to launch our rocket toward an azimuth about 3.4 degrees
(atan 465/7800) west of north or south, with an ascent profile such that its final velocity relative to the launch site is 7814
m/s (by the Pythagorean theorem), as shown in this diagram:

[image: Hypotenuse to cancel rotation]

Thus, it costs about an extra 14 m/s of $\Delta v$ to cancel the
rotation when launching to polar LEO from the equator.

Meanwhile, if we launch from one of the poles, we don't need to cancel
any rotation, but we're about 20 km further below our target altitude.
(Note: For the purposes of this crude calculation, the atmosphere is
essentially the same at both locations.  The
[troposphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troposphere) is thinner
at the poles, but that is not relevant, as its edge is determined
by the temperature gradient.  At all surface locations (assuming
calm weather!), the atmosphere is in
[hydrostatic equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatics#Hydrostatic_pressure),
leading to a density profile that is practically the same for our
purposes, the relevant portion of which is entirely inside the
troposphere at both locations.)

So, let's assume we use the same ascent profile as before, but initially
targeting an altitude 20 km lower, thus expending the same $\Delta v$,
minus the 14 m/s.  Then, let's use a
[Hohmann Transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohmann_transfer_orbit)
to climb the extra 20 km of altitude.  (We can use
[this calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/hohmann-transfer),
among others.)  It costs a combined 12 m/s of $\Delta v$ to do the two
burns of that transfer.

However, that's not the most efficient mission plan, since it's better
to launch directly to the target altitude, and then circularize a single
time once there, than to make a stop in a parking orbit partway up.  So
12 m/s is an upper bound on the cost of the extra 20 km of altitude.

Since the equatorial launch required 14 m/s to cancel the Earth rotation,
and the polar launch required at most 12 m/s to gain the extra 20 km of
altitude, we can conclude that the polar launch is more efficient, when
only considering $\Delta v$.

Of course, even if the difference was the full 14 m/s, that would not
come close to compensating for the enormous logistical costs of
launching from either pole.  Practically speaking, if you want to get
into a polar orbit, you launch from wherever is logistically convenient
and has a clear range to either the north or south.

Comment: How would the choice of polar versus equatorial launch point affect the required thrust/mass ratio at take-off and the size of engines required to achieve it?

Comment: Interestingly the OP did not specify a timeframe, so we don't know if they are asking about using current technology which is very labor intensive, or technology say 100 years in the future. Obviously the physics won't change in 100 years, but the technology certainly will, we just don't know how. It's easy to imagine space launches becoming much more heavily automated in the future, in which case the economics might tilt in favor of polar launches far up into the polar circles, even if not necessarily directly on the poles. And maybe more eastward launches from closer to their ideal latitude.

Comment: @supercat I'm not aware of anything that would significantly affect required TWR or engine size, assuming sea-level launches.  (The ice surface right at the south pole is not at sea level, but I omitted consideration of that under the "uniform oblate spheroid" assumption.)

Comment: @Scott McPeak Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I wanted to hear. I couldn’t understand why so many people write that it is necessary to cancel for all 465 m/s if in fact this value is 14 m/s (as you described). I already thought that something was wrong with me)))

Comment: Ambient temperature would impact air density, which would impact drag and specific impulse. In that respect the equatorial heat is better.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that, although the effect of changing the launch _altitude_ is quite small (< 12 m/s), so is the effect of changing the _latitude_ (≈ 14 m/s) as well, making the two at least roughly comparable in magnitude. I would not have expected that.

Comment: There's something very wrong with this answer. For one thing, it omits the plane change at the end of the burn. For another, it implicitly assumes an impulsive burn at liftoff. Even if we could do that, doing so would qualify not just as a "bad idea" but as a "very, very bad idea" as going through the thick lower atmosphere at Mach 25 is not going to do good things to the spacecraft. As of the time of this comment, I am the sole downvoter. I do not understand all the upvotes.

Comment: @DavidHammen the described launch seems to place the spacecraft into a 90 degree inclination orbit and doesn't say the spacecraft stays in the lower atmosphere. Where are you reading that?

Comment: @DavidHammen There's no intention to change planes at any point.  The launch azimuth of 3.4 degrees W cancels the launch site motion relative to Earth's center, so upon achieving orbital velocity, the orbital plane inclination is 90 degrees.  The ascent profile is meant to be typical for modern staged rockets, taking ~10 minutes to fully accelerate, most of which is above the lower atmosphere.  I've edited the answer slightly, changing "total velocity" to "final velocity w.r.t. launch site", to hopefully clarify that.

Comment: The popular "polar" LEO orbits are really those with inclination from roughly 80° to 100° If I was ambitious or had had more coffee, I'd make a histogram, but you can review the table of sun-synchronous orbits at the bottom of [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun-synchronous_orbit#Technical_details) (97.7° or 99.0°) or look at the polar part of the Starlink constellation at 97.6°.  How would the numbers work for thiese popular polar orbits?

Comment: *"but we're about 20 km deeper in the gravitational well"* Mean sea level is (approximately) an equipotential surface. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geopotential Note that the ocean isn't ~20 km deep at the North Pole. ;)

Comment: Here's a classic Physics.SE post on the gravitational potential of the ellipsoidal Earth: [Why is the Earth so fat?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8074/123208)

Comment: @PM2Ring You're right, that was clumsy phrasing.  I wasn't meaning to say gravity was stronger at the pole, just suggest a frame of reference that isn't tied to a surface location.  I've changed it to say "20 km further below the target altitude".

Comment: @uhoh It's not clear how to do a meaningful comparison since SSO can't be reached from a pole (without a plane change maneuver).  Maybe you have in mind to compare with launching westward from (say) 83 degrees N/S?

Comment: @ScottMcPeak that's what I get for logging in before my coffee kicks in. Now that I've got a few synapses firing, I'm thinking that if I were still posting questions I would ask something like "From what latitude could a given rocket put the most mass into a 97.7° 567 km sun-synchronous orbit?" In the body of the question I'd allow the answer author to choose some standard, well document rocket of their choice to avoid the "depends on" trap.

Answer (score 17):

When a rocket launches from the equator, it also has the velocity from Earth's rotation. Normally this would be a good thing because then a rocket does not need as much delta V. Since Earth is rotating at [1 670 km/h](https://study.com/academy/lesson/earths-rotation-facts-speed.html) at the equator, that is a free 463,8 m/s of delta V.

[image]

However, a rocket launching into a polar orbit would have to use more fuel since it would have to counteract the movement of Earth's rotation. [Earth rotates the slowest at the poles and the fastest at the equator](https://sciengsustainability.blogspot.com/2013/04/faster-than-sound-our-velocity-due-to.html). This means that the best place to launch into a polar orbit is the poles because there the Earth is rotating the slowest and the rocket requires less fuel to counteract the rotation of Earth.

The height difference plays a really small role. Rockets normally have to reach about 8km/s to reach orbit, maybe also another 2km/s to get above the Karman line. Starting 20km higher does not really change that much in terms of delta V. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4m75t4x1V2o) by the Everyday Astronaut explains the situation really well. The delta V saved by not having to counteract the rotation definitely is much more than the delta V saved by starting 20 km higher.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the video. 
But the video doesn't say anything about gravitational losses. In addition to horizontal velocity, you need to achieve a target altitude. the higher the target altitude, the longer the flight time and, as a result, the greater the gravitational losses.

Comment: Mandatory [xkcd](https://what-if.xkcd.com/58/). "_getting to space is easy. The problem is staying there_".

Comment: Other than the first few seconds of liftoff, there aren't gravitational "losses" to speak of. It's incorrect to think of an orbit as [Energy to gain altitude] + [Energy to gain horizontal velocity]. The horizontal velocity itself is what determines the altitude of an orbit, and the only reason we spend fuel going up first is so that the initial minutes of building that horizontal speed pass through less atmosphere (and landscape).

Comment: @JayMcEh: Only a tiny fraction of a mission's time will be spent during "the first few seconds of liftoff" , but the rate at which fuel is burned during that time will be so much greater than the rate of fuel burn later in the mission that the fraction of overall mission fuel will be significant.

Comment: @supercat can you give an example of a booster where the "rate at which fuel is burned" (i.e., kg/s) is significantly greater at liftoff than a few seconds (or even a minute) later?

Comment: @JayMcEh The term "gravity losses" (some  use "gravity drag" instead) reflects the fact that launch is not impulsive. A finite burn performed in a non-constant gravity field inherently requires more energy than does an impulsive burn that achieves the same end.

Comment: @supercat Thrust oftentimes is temporarily throttled down near maxQ (typically a minute or so after launch, but that reduction is only temporary), and later is throttled down near the end of the burn to limit acceleration (but that is much later rather than a few seconds after launch).

Comment: @DavidHammen: I'm not clear how many seconds is "a few".  The difference between the required delta V using actual rockets, versus total the delta V that would be required if all remaining delta V could be applied in an impulse, falls off rapidly during the early part of a mission, and at some moment will be small enough that other factors would be more important, but my intended point--which I failed to state--is that while the fraction of a mission's total V that is imparted before that moment is small, the fraction of the fuel that is spent before that moment is by comparison much larger.

Comment: [ditto](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/65340/why-does-everyone-say-that-it-is-better-to-launch-a-satellite-into-polar-orbit-f#comment217971_65347)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much of a factor it is in total launch budget, but atmosphere thickness probably has an effect on launches between the two locations.

Atmospheric thickness varies, it is thickest at the equator and thinnest at the poles, meaning launching from the equator would encounter more drag during it's longer path through the thicker atmosphere.

Comment: What really matters is density. The polar air is more dense than tropical due to temperature differences. The thickness, while significant (6km vs 20km) is overshadowed by the rotational speed.

Comment: Launching from either pole has environmental and logistical issues - Cannot pollute in Antarctica, and the Arctic lacks stable land (its all ice)